# connect in a function from a parent file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have 2  files: `qdialog1.py` and `qdialog2.py`

when `qdialog2` is rejected, I need to connect with myfunction from `qdialog1`

`qdialog1` is a parent and `qdialog2` is its child

anyone could help me?

**qdialog1.py**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog

from Ui_dialog1 import Ui_dialog1
from qdialog2 import Qdialog2

class QDialog1(QDialog, Ui_dialog1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSignature("")
    def on_pbUpdate_clicked(self):
        dlg = QDialog2(self)
        dlg.setModal(True)
        dlg.show()

    def myfunction(self):
        self.lineedit.clear()
```

**qdialog2.py**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog

from Ui_dialog2 import Ui_dialog2

class QDialog2(QDialog, Ui_dialog2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.rejected.connect() # I need help here to call qdialog1.myfunction()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must connect it via parent

```
self.rejected.connect(parent.myfunction)
```